# Intellij Idea Code wrapping when formatted

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, word-wrap

I am new to Intellij Idea. I didn't find any information on how to wrap the code after certain characters (ex: 150 characters, break the line)

[image]

I want to break the code after the vertical line, the following code must come in next line.

Note: I used *Reformat* code option, but it did just realigned the code with some white spaces etc, but not wrapping up the code. It's difficult to see the end of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go to **Settings**  (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) then select **Code Style** - **General**
Here you can configure your margins and if you want the code to wrap after it reaches the end of it

[image: Code style general]